# I used the os.path.join() method and it only works if two other functions are NOT called. (No error message)

Tags: python, operating-system, scandir

The (later) plan for my project is this: iterate through my downloaded files, automatically create subfolders, sort my files by keywords and move them to subfolders matching the keywords.
A prototype already worked. I don't understand, why this supposedly clean written sketch does not.

Every function works when called individually.
When I call them together the create_dir_by_keyword() function does not work, but does not give me an error message.
I suspect it does not work because I iterate through `os.scandir(dir_keyword_files)` multiple times?
But why would it not work? Sorry, I am lost here.

```
import os


dir_source_files = 'source files'
dir_destination = 'destination'
dir_keyword_files = 'keywords'

scanned_dir_source_files = os.scandir(dir_source_files)
scanned_dir_keyword_files = os.scandir(dir_keyword_files)
scanned_dir_destination = os.scandir(dir_destination)

def scan_dir_source_files():
    for file in scanned_dir_source_files:
        print(file)
    print("scan_dir_source_files() function called\n")


def scan_dir_keyword_files():
    for file in scanned_dir_keyword_files:
        print(file)
    print("scan_dir_keyword_files() function called\n")

def read_keywords():
    for file in scanned_dir_keyword_files:
        keywords_in_file = open(file, 'r')
        print(f"keyword found: {keywords_in_file.read()}")
    print("read_keywords() function called\n")


def create_dir_by_keyword():
    #reads the title of a scanned .txt and creates a subfolder with that title in dir_destination folder
    for file in scanned_dir_keyword_files:
        print((f"\nfile found in dir_keyword_files:\n{file} name of new folder: " + os.path.splitext(file.name)[0]))
        new_dir_name = str(os.path.splitext(file.name)[0])
        path_for_new_dir = os.path.join(dir_destination, new_dir_name)
        try:
            os.makedirs(path_for_new_dir, exist_ok = False)
            print(f"directory creation succesful. created directory:\n{new_dir_name}")
        except OSError as error:
            print(f"directory creation not succesful. '{new_dir_name}' already exists")
    print("create_dir_by_keyword() function called\n")

scan_dir_source_files()
scan_dir_source_files()
read_keywords()
create_dir_by_keyword()
```

Every function works by itself and individually, but if I call `create_dir_by_keyword()` together with `scan_dir_source_files()` and `read_keywords()` no subfolder is created.

output:

```
<DirEntry 'How to Read People Like a Book -James W. Williams -Full Audiobook (192kbit_AAC).m4a'>
<DirEntry 'How to Talk to Anyone 92 Little Tricks for Big Success in Relationships Audiobook (128kbit_AAC).m4a'>
scan_dir_source_files() function called

scan_dir_source_files() function called

keyword found: 'audiobook', 'hÃ¶rbuch', 'podcast'
read_keywords() function called

create_dir_by_keyword() function called
```

---

Tried to code this extra readable.
Feedback on the readability of my code is welcome.

Comment: Is the second call to `scan_dir_source_files` supposed to call `scan_dir_keyword_files`?

Comment: `os.scandir()` returns a generator. You can only loop over it once. You should convert it to a list if you want to loop over it repeatedly.

Comment: Since you asked for ideas to improve your code: functions should get all the data they need via parameter(s). Don't rely on the existence of global variables. This is harder to maintain and less reusable.

Comment: @Matthias
Thank you for the feedback. The program now runs smoothly and I will use parameters from now on.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. The problem was indeed os.scandir() and now everything runs smoothly.